# Casting pointer to pointer in a type-safe manner

Tags: c++, pointers

Given the following piece of code:

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base { };

int main(void)
{
  Derived d;
  Base* pb = &d;
  Base** ppb = &pb;

  Derived** ppd = ...; // Can this be defined in a type-safe manner?

  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to give a type-safe expression for the assignment to `ppd`, without introducing an intermediary variable of type `Derived*`?

Comment: There's no `Dervied*` object for `ppd` to point to. You'd first have to introduce one. Before you ask, `pb` is not it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have updated the question, so that it is clear the idea is not to introduce an object of `ppd` to point to.

Comment: A valid pointer of type `T*` is either null, or points to an object of type `T`. As you don't have an object of type `Derived*` anywhere in your program, nor are you willing to introduce one, `ppd` can only be null. I assume `Derived** ppd = nullptr;` is not quite the answer you were looking for.

Comment: No.   A `Derived **` is not a `Base **`.  Any conversion from one to the other is not typesafe, whether you introduce an intermediary variable or not.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks. I like the `nullptr` solution :) But indeed not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, not without declaring a `Derived` pointer to `d`. The `Base` pointer to `d` (`pb`) has already lost type information through abstraction, which cannot be recovered without a unsafe cast.

Since you're declaring a pointer to a pointer to a `Derived`, you need a pointer to a `Derived` first. Eg:

```
Derived* pd = &d;
Derived** ppd = &pd;
```

Both of those definitions are type-safe, checked at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to give a type-safe expression for the assignment to `ppd`, without introducing an intermediary variable of type `Derived*`?

Well, there is the obviously safe option:

```
Derived** ppd = nullptr;
```

Otherwise: No. The only object that a `Derived**` can safely point at is `Derived*`. You don't have a `Derived*` object nor are you interested in introducing one, so you cannot point to one.

Note that `Base*` is *not* a base of `Derived*`, so there is no polymorphic relationship between `Base**` and `Derived**` like there is between `Base*`and `Derived*`.